# Compress HTTP responses using Kestrel and .NET core middleware

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware, kestrel-http-server

I'm looking to encode HTTP responses on the fly using .NET Core and the Kestrel web server. The following code does not work, the response fails to load in the browser.

```
        var response = context.Response;


        if (encodingsAccepted.ToArray().Any(x => x.Contains("gzip")))
        {
            // Set Gzip stream.
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            // Wrap response body in Gzip stream.
            var body = context.Response.Body;


            context.Response.Body = new GZipStream(body, CompressionMode.Compress);


        }
```

Answer (score 16):

**The detailed description** about response compression is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression

**A quick summary**
Compression can be enabled in 2 steps:

1. Add a reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression` package.
2. Enable compression on the application startup:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddResponseCompression();
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   {
       app.UseResponseCompression();

       ...
   }
   ```

That's it. Now the response will be compressed in case if the client accepts compression encoding.

Comment: Be mindful that if you are using https, you will need to use the `EnableForHttps` option in the `AddResponseCompression` call. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-3.1#compression-with-secure-protocol

Answer (score 0):

All of that must occur before invoking the next middleware (e.g. `_next.Invoke` or what have you), then after invoking the next middleware, you should `await context.Response.Body.FlushAsync();`.